# Does Drupal resave the photo even if it's already the correct size as your Image Style?

Tags: 7, media

Does Drupal still recompress the photo even if the file you uploaded is *already* the same size as your selected Image Style? In the event that it does recompress it, is there a way to prevent it? Image quality is at stake in this case since it saves it in JPG.

Comment: You observed the same problem as I did, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/246398/image-derivative-size-different-from-original-even-in-absence-of-any-effect

Comment: I also created a Drupal 7 core issue for this, see https://www.drupal.org/node/2914964

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran some **Md5 tests** and sadly it *does* recompress it again even if it's already the correct dimensions. Is there *some* way to prevent this? Uncool.